# php with full_special_chars enabled delivers wrong $_GET array

Tags: php, filter, get

i have the following problem:

these settings are in php.ini

```
filter.default = full_special_chars
filter.default_flags = 0
```

if a url like the following is requested from the server:

```
http://server/action?param1=a&param2=b
```

the $_GET will contain one key "amp;param2".

how can i avoid that? (other then disabling the settings above :) )

php version: PHP 5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 20 2012 22:55:53)

Answer (score 0):

Use `html_entity_decode()`. Refer [this!!](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$a=htmlentities($_GET['url']); //$a=amp;blah

$b=html_entity_decode($a); //$b=&blah
```

Comment: the url is not a parameter. the string mentioned above is entered in the browser's adress. param2 is the actual parameter

Comment: @memical That was just an example. you can send your parameter